# How to sign a Deb package with dpkg-sig and GPG2 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, gnupg

I have a script which is used to sign a deb and build a repo.
The relevant code is below that is causing issues:

```sh
export GNUPGHOME=foo/gnupg/
killall -q gpg-agent
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --homedir $GNUPGHOME --allow-preset-passphrase)
echo ${signPass} | /usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset $fingerprint
dpkg-sig -g '--no-tty' --sign builder bar/baz/app.deb
```

This is working on Ubuntu 14.04 but as soon as I attempt to run this on a server with Ubuntu 16.04 installed it I get the following errors:

```
dpkg-deb: building package 'app' in 'bar/baz/app.deb'.
Processing bar/baz/app.deb..
gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input
E: Signing failed. Error code: 512
```

---

**Ubuntu 14.04 packages:**

- gnupg - 1.4.16-1ubuntu2.3
- gnupg-agent - 2.0.22-3ubuntu1.3
- gnupg2 - 2.0.22-3ubuntu1.3
- gpgv - 1.4.16-1ubuntu2.3

**Ubuntu 16.04 packages:**

- gnupg - 1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1
- gnupg-agent 2.1.11-6ubuntu2
- gnupg2 - 2.1.11-6ubuntu2
- gpgv - 1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1
- gpgv2 - 2.1.11-6ubuntu2

I know that `dpkg-sig` calls `/usr/bin/gpg` directly, and I have used `update-alternatives` to set `/usr/bin/gpg` to be `gpg2` but that gives me errors with “inappropiate ioctl for device”.
Any suggestions would be great, as I have been banging my head for a while.

**Extra Info:**

This script is run as part of a build job on 'Bamboo'.
The password is passed through as an environment variable, as it is securely stored. I am not looking to change the pipeline of this app though.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! From where does `${signPass}` come? In any case there's an equally secure but far simpler solutions that don't involve a GPG agent but it depends on the particular source of the pass phrase. Please [edit] your question to add relevant information and send me a notification comment (with `@DavidFoerster` somewhere in the text).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you for the warm welcome. I have added section at the bottom of the requested information. Hopefully this provides context.

Comment: If you can store the password securely you could just as well store a *password-less key file* securely (which is the recommended procedure for key files that are to be used by unattended processes) and pass its path to `dpkg-sig` with the `-f` option. I'll write a complete answer later.

Answer (score 3):

You say that the pass phrase in `${signPass}` comes from some secure storage. If you can store a pass phrase securely you could also store a key chain with a *password-less secret key* securely.

1. Change the password of the key to empty. You can use your favourite key chain manager or the following command:

   ```sh
   GNUPGHOME=... gpg2 --passwd user_id
   ```
2. Store the key chain in secure storage.
3. Run `dpkg-sig` with GPG options that use the securely stored key chain:

   ```sh
   dpkg-sig --gpg-options "--secret-keyring /path/to/secret-keyring.gpg"
   ```

---

Alternatively you can use a pass phrase file *directly* with `dpkg-sig` (**see the edit below**):

```sh
dpkg-sig -f /path/to/pass-phrase ...
```

You could even use standard input:

```sh
printf '%s' "${signPass}" | dpkg-sig -f - ...
```

**Edit:** It appears that a [long standing bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg-sig/+bug/1630542) breaks the `-f` option but you can work around it via `--gpg-options '--passphrase-file /path/to/pass-phrase'` (except that you can't use passphrase file names with white-space).

Comment: dpkg-sign fails when I am attempting to pass -f /path/to/passfile:

Comment: I am trying them on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, all latest package version (after recent sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade):

dpkg-sig fails when I am attempting to pass -f /path/to/passfile:
dpkg-sig --sign builder -f password.txt -k 12345678 mypackage_0.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Processing mypackage_0.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb...
usage: gpg [options] --clearsign [filename]
E: Signing failed. Error code: 512

Comment: dpkg-sig also fails when trying to use "-f -"

    echo "my secret key password" | dpkg-sig -f - --sign builder -k 12345678 mypackage_0.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    Processing xiota-proxy_0.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb...
    sh: 1: cannot open -: No such file
    E: Signing failed. Error code: 512

But works good when I am running just

    dpkg-sig --sign builder -k 12345678 mypackage_0.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

but I have to enter password manually.

Comment: any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I have found LP bug report for this issue. The bug was reported ~1.5 years ago, confirmed, but still not fixed. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg-sig/+bug/1630542

Comment: So effectively dpkg-sig -f doesn't work.

Comment: Suggested workaround: use -g '--passphrase-file FILE' to bypass dpkg-sig erroneous handling and send the passphrase file directly to gpg.

Comment: @ivan.ukr: Thanks! I added a suitable note to my answer. Could you please remove your comments to unclutter the comment section a little now that the issue has been dealt with?

Comment: In order to use a "password-less" system with gpg >= 2.x, you should take a look to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase/415064#415064